# R Code ignored nargs() if statement

Tags: r, args

Cannot figure out why R is ignoring `nargs()` in following

```
foo <- function(x=NULL) {

  if (nargs() > 1){
    stop("Enter 1 argument only")
  }
  cat("call was ", deparse(match.call()), "\n", sep = "")
}
```

When I execute `foo("a","b")`, I get `Error in foo("a", "b") : unused argument ("b")` instead of `Enter 1 argument only`.

Please advise

Comment: If you have multiple arguments, use `...`.  i.e. `function(...) {` In your function, there is only a single parameter 'x' and you are supplying two with `foo("a", "b")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For multiple arguments, we can use three dots (`...`) and the condition with `nargs` will evaluate it

```
foo <- function(...) {

 if (nargs() > 1){
  stop("Enter 1 argument only")
 }
  cat("call was ", deparse(match.call()), "\n", sep = "")
 }

foo("a", "b")
```

> Error in foo("a", "b") : Enter 1 argument only

```
foo("a")
#call was foo("a")
```